# How to open and Set focus on a Mat selection List item within an Accordion programatically

Tags: focus

I am new to Angular, and I am trying to open an accordion/expansion panel containing a mat-selection-list programatically, or by data binding.

here is the html: everything is working nicely -  however when the user clicks on the dialog I want it to set focus on a list selection that they are looking at in my app: specifically devChain.name

```
<div *ngIf="sessionInfo$ | async as sessionInfo">

    <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let devotional of sessionInfo.library" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
            (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>{{devotional.title}}</mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <ng-container *ngIf="devotional.devChain">
                <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" 
                #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)"
                hideSingleSelectionIndicator="true">
                    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let devChain of devotional.devChain" [value]=devChain.name
>
                        {{ devChain.name }}
                    </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

Here is the .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { GlobalService } from "../global.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './libraryDialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './libraryDialog.component.scss' ],
})
export class LibraryDialogComponent  {

  panelOpenState = true;

  sessionInfo$ = this._globalService.Session$;


    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LibraryDialogComponent>,
        private _globalService: GlobalService,
    ) { }

  
    onNgModelChange(event:any){
      console.log('on ng model change', event);
    }
  
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

I've tried several options, but am stuck